# How do I select the base class from the child object in Django (using model inheritance)

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I have a base model and one that inherits from it, similar in setup to this:

```
class Archive(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()


class ArchiveB(Archive):
    another_date = models.DateField()
```

How do I access the base class from the child class? For example:

```
archiveb_instance = ArchiveB.objects.get(pk=5) 
base_instance = archiveb_instance.archive #This doesn't work.
```

According to the documentation its just a one-to-one relationship automatically created in the child so I figured it would let me go backwards. The reason I want this is because I have a third non-Archive model that has a foreignkey to Archive. I want the foreignkey to Archive because this way the third model can relate to any Archive, not just a specific Archive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you might be looking for `archiveb_instance.archive_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

They share the same PK, so just assign that to the field with `_id` appended.

Comment: The above answer was the correct solution for me. Just to note, I don't think they necessarily share the same PK (ie, if I created a few Archive records that do not include ArchiveB records and then create a bunch of ArchiveB records.). In this case the PK for the two tables would not match.

Comment: Yes, they would. The PK of the base is what the `OneToOneField` in the child contains.